# Hyperlink is not working in email

Tags: node.js

I am using node mailer module in nodejs  using SMTP.

here is my code.

```
    var email  = require('../libs/email');

/* Send an Email */


    var mailOptions = {
                            to:emailId, // list of receivers
                            subject: 'Change Password Request', // Subject line
                            html: "<a target='_blank' href='"+req.headers.host+"/resetpassword/"+email_token+"'>click here</a>"
                    };

email.sendEmail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
                    if(!error){

                    }else{

                    }
                });
```

i got an email, but it is not clickable .  i am using gmail

Any idea how to rectify this issuse

Thanks

Comment: if the link to a publicly available server? (eg. not localhost or a server on your LAN). From memory, gmail won't link to servers which it doesn't think are real.

Comment: but i am testing with live url.

Comment: hmmm.. you are using single quotes. which are valid in HTML, but maybe the gmail processor doesn't like them. worth a shot.

Comment: what should i do now?

Comment: i would turn the single quotes to double quotes, and then try different things: change the domain name to see if that's the issue. remove the target. etc. see if the link works in other mail clients

Comment: i found that. i was missing http in this :)